# How do I get a button to delete the appended list element that it is attached to?

Tags: javascript, jquery, list

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  let counter = 0;

  $("#btn").on("click", () => {
    let task = $("#text").val();
    let deleteBtnId = "delete" + counter;
    let listElement = "<li>"+ task + "<button id="+deleteBtnId+"> X </button></li>";

    $("ul").append(listElement);

    $("#" + deleteBtnId).on("click", () => {
      $(this).parent().remove(); // Fix: Use $(this).parent().remove()
    });

    counter++;
  });
});
```

I tried to create each with a unique id so that it could be targeted and deleted. However, it is not working. What do you see that could be wrong?

Comment: Hi, change `$("this").remove();` this to `$("#"+ deleteBtnId).closest("li").remove();`

Comment: Change `$("#" + deleteBtnId).on("click", ()=>{ $("this").remove(); });` to `$("#" + deleteBtnId).on("click", function() { $(this).remove(); });`   `$(this)` should not be in quotes and you can't use `this` with arrow functions (`=>`) so use `function()`

Comment: In addition, remove the `id=deleteBtnId` and also use `listElement.find("button").on("click"...`   (calculated IDs are a nasty crutch that cause more problems than they solve)

Answer (score 0):

Use classes instead of ids. Add a `delete` class to each button. When it's clicked you can use jQuery's [`parent`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) method to get the list item element of which the button is a child and [`remove`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) it.

In addition you can use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) by attaching *one* listener to the list element that catches events from every element with a `delete` class.

```js
// Cache the list element
const list = $('ul');

// Delegate the listener to the list to watch
// out for events from the child elements with the
// delete class. Remove that element's parent element.
list.on('click', '.delete', function () {
  $(this).parent().remove();
});

$('#addTask').on('click', function () {

  // Get the task text
  const task = $('#text').val();

  // Create a button
  const button = $('<button></button')
    .attr('type', 'button')
    .addClass('delete')
    .text('X');

  // Create an item - attach the task text
  // and the button
  const item = $('<li></li>')
    .text(task)
    .append(button);

  // Attach the item to the list
  list.append(item);

});
```

```css
.delete { margin-left: 0.25rem; }
.delete:hover { cursor: pointer; background-color: #ffaaaa;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="text" />
<button type="button" id="addTask">Add task</button>
<ul></ul>
```

Here's the same code written with vanilla JS using native DOM methods.

```js
// Cache some elements
const addTask = document.querySelector('#addTask');
const list = document.querySelector('ul');
const input = document.querySelector('#text');

// Add listeners to the list and addTask button elements
list.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
addTask.addEventListener('click', handleAdd);

// The list catches elements from its child elements
// If the element that fires an event is one with a "delete"
// class remove that element's parent element.
function handleClick(e) {
  if (e.target.matches('.delete')) {
    e.target.parentElement.remove();
  }
}

function handleAdd(e) {
  
  // Get the task text
  const task = input.value;
  
  // Create a list item using a template string
  const item = `
    <li>
      ${task}
      <button type="button" class="delete">
        X
      </button>
    </li>
  `;

  // Add the item to the list
  list.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', item);

}
```

```css
.delete { margin-left: 0.25rem; }
.delete:hover { cursor: pointer; background-color: #ffaaaa;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="text" />
<button type="button" id="addTask">Add task</button>
<ul></ul>
```

Additional documentation

- [Template/string literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)
- [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)
- [`matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches)